# What is the name of this Florida shrub?

Tags: identification

[image]

We thought it was a Petticoat bush but can’t find that anywhere. 
It has:
Orbicular Detate Cordate rounded alternate pinnately veined leaves

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be *[Acalypha wilkesiana](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Acalypha_wilkesiana_forma_circinata.jpg)* forma *circinata*. The dentate/ serrate, variegated margins are quite distinctive. I'm not familiar with this form but the genus in general are hardy, easy to grow plants.

Comment: Hello Ben,  Can you please expand on your answer. I can see from the picture you are correct, but please give us some more information.  What do you know about the genus?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this interesting puzzle. The odd thing about the leaves illustrated is that they don't appear to have a main central midrib which should be a major clue to the identity but it isn't. The leaves appear to be somewhat distorted, so it is possible that this is not the shape of a true leaf, but one which has been artificially bent from what it should be. There are a number of reasons this might happen, including viruses and herbicides, so an additional detail or two might be are there any other leaves on this or nearby shrubs that are more "normal" or are they overhanging a lawn which has been sprayed for broadleaf weeds?

We might try to imagine what the leaf would look like if it had a normal central midrib and a flat appearance. [*Elaeagnus pungens*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elaeagnus_pungens) is one shrub which is highly variable and frequently shows odd variegation which might explain the white tipped lobes. The leaves are somewhat large for E. pungens but in conditions of generous feeding might happen.

Since there are not many responses yet you might add some details about the bark at the base of the shrub, a detail shot of branch/twig colouration, an overall shot, height, any flowers or fruit visible. More detail would definitely be helpful if the leaf shape shown is a red herring.

Edit: I think this might be a new variegated hibiscus. Take a look at [this photo from Texas A & M](https://today.agrilife.org/2017/09/15/colorful-winter-hardy-hibiscus-hybrids-continue-trek-consumer-gardens/dsc_1077-2/) - note how the leaf venation becomes very confused, some have central vein and others quite randomly netted. The variegation is clearly less pronounced in your sample.